# If my non-US cousin sends me money in the US to buy his car, will I be taxed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, money-transfer, income

I have a cousin living abroad, who wants to buy a car here in the US. He wants to send the money to my account so I can buy it for him. The car costs about $75,000, and he will pay my $500 to do the leg work. Will I get taxed if this money gets deposited in my account?

Comment: Have you ever met this cousin? Are you sure he’s who he says he is?

Comment: This may throw up some fraud-related red flags through the bank transfer, or at some other stage in the process. Before agreeing to do this, be sure that your documentation is all in order, and that you are 100% confident that everything is legally okay.

Comment: he is a real cousin he just wants to send a nice car home to use

Comment: Is your cousin's name going to go on the title? He doesn't have to give the money to you. He can simply wire the money directly to the dealership. It's much cleaner that way.

Comment: He can afford a $75k new car but can't work out himself how to buy a car not in person? Truly the world is not a fair place.

Comment: How is the car going to get to him for him to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Gift taxes are paid by the giver, not the "givee".

You'd have to claim the $500 on your income tax forms, though.

Comment: And it's not a gift if the money is used to buy something for the 'giver'.

Comment: @DJClayworth correct.  OP will have to keep documentation about where that much cash came from.  An alphabet soup of government agencies are going to be suspicious.

Comment: It is money being provided in exchange for services. That is not a gift, that is income.

Answer (score 0):

Also, depending where you buy the car in the US, you have to pay property tax every year for just having purchased the car.

Answer (score 0):

If you are being paid money in exchange for services that you are providing to your cousin, then that is income, are legally you are required to declare it as self-employment income, and pay taxes when you file your tax return (and if you have a significant amount of self-employment income, you're supposed make payments every quarter of your estimated tax liability. The deposit itself will not be taxed, however.